# Draggable JQuery - allow div's to return to parent on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I am pretty new to JQuery and have worked through a series of tutorials on the web and answers on this website but I can't work this out and would appreciated any help.

I am trying to create a function where there are a series of draggable and droppable divs. Each are only accepted into the relevant slots.

Once in the slots a little 'x' appears which the user can click to send the draggable element back to its parent.

I'm almost there this code almost works - I have the slots, I have the draggable element. The 'x' appears when it stops but I can get the 'x' to work to make the div return home.

Any help appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
Drag and drop</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( init );

function init() {
// Reset 
$('#defPile').html( '' );
$('#defSlots').html( '' );
$('#gkPile').html( '' );
$('#gkSlots').html( '' );

// Create defenders
  var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
  var position = 'd';  
  for ( var i=0; i<4; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + "<span class='undo' style='display:none'>x</span> </div>").data( 'number', numbers[i] ).data( 'position', 'd' ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i]  ).appendTo( '#defPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#defPile div',
      revert: 'invalid',
      stop: function(event, ui){
        $(this).find('.undo').show();   
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
      }
    } );
  } 

    // Create the pile gk cards
  var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
  var position = 'g';

  for ( var i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + "<span class='undo' style='display:none'>x</span></div>").data( 'number', numbers[i] ).data( 'position', 'g' ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#gkPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#gkPile div',
      revert: 'invalid',
      stop: function(event, ui){
        $(this).find('.undo').show();   
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
      }
    } );
  }

     // Create the def slots
  var words = [ 'def' ];
    $('<div>' + 'defender' + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#defSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#defPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
  drop: handleCardDrop      
    } );

     // Create the gk slots
  var words = [ 'gk' ];
    $('<div>' + 'goalie' + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#gkSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#gkPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop      
    } );

 }


function handleCardDrop(event,ui ) {
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',false);
    if (!ui.draggable.data("originalPosition")) {
        ui.draggable.data("originalPosition",
                          ui.draggable.data("draggable").originalPosition);
                          $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    }


  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );
  var position = ui.draggable.data( 'position' );


    //ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
     ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    //$(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );

    //$(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
}

$('.gkPile').find('.undo').click(function(i, e) {
    var $div = $(this).parent();
    revertDraggable($div);
});

$('.defPile').find('.undo').click(function(i, e) {
    var $div = $(this).parent();
    revertDraggable($div);
});

function revertDraggable($selector) {
    $selector.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        position = $this.data("originalPosition");

        if (position) {
            $this.animate({
            left: position.left,
            top: position.top
        }, 500, function() {
            $this.data("originalPosition", null);
        });
    }
    });
        $selector.find('.undo').hide();

}

</script>

 </head>
<body>

<div id="content">

  <div id="defPile"> </div>
  <div id="defSlots"> </div>

<div id="gkPile"> </div>
  <div id="gkSlots"> </div>

 </div>

</div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

There is a working example at: http://www.lfc-predictions.co.uk/dragtest/index3.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a look at the page and it looks like you are very close!
Just need to change the selectors for the click events from ***class*** selectors to ***id*** selectors

```
$('#gkPile').find('.undo').click(function(i, e) {
    var $div = $(this).parent();
    revertDraggable($div);
});

$('#defPile').find('.undo').click(function(i, e) {
    var $div = $(this).parent();
    revertDraggable($div);
});
```

For jQuery selectors use ***#*** for ids and ***.*** for classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made your change, still didnt work. But then I popped it into jsfiddle and it worked! So I bumped up my JQuery version and we've got there.Thanks so much for your speedy and accurate reply!

Comment: One final question. I can reverse the code to make the element draggable on the return. But using your code above. How would I make the slot droppable again? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your welcome =) Looks like you disable droppable. Just add `$div.closest('.ui-droppable').droppable('enable');` when you set originalPosition to null and you should be ok. If that doesn't work try `$('.ui-droppable').droppable('enable');` And if that works you just have to find a way to enable the right drop zone.

Comment: Cheers. Putting $('.ui-droppable').droppable('enable'); in the click function works! thanks for your help